# How add condition in wordpress shortcode loop

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I want to multiple of 2 close div and open a new div in wp loop using shortcode post loop.

```
if($i % 2 == 0) {echo '</li><li>';}

  $i++;
```

How Can do it?

General loop:

```
<?php
  $i = 1;
//added before to ensure it gets opened
echo '<li>';
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
     // post stuff...
  ?>
    <div class="frCol"><a href="#"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'imgthumb')); ?></a>
    <div class="item-info">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </div>
    </div>
 <?php
     // if multiple of 3 close div and open a new div
     if($i % 2 == 0) {echo '</li><li>';}
  $i++; endwhile; endif;
//make sure open div is closed
echo '</li>';
 ?>
```

This is the shortcode:

```
function testimonial_thumb_shortcode($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'category' => ''
    ), $atts));
    $q = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'testimonials',
        'testimonial_cat' => $category
    ));
    $list = ' <ul>';
    while($q->have_posts()):
        $q->the_post();
        $idd = get_the_ID();
        $author_photo = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail');
        $list .= '/*Main loop*/';
    endwhile;
    $list.= '</ul>';
    wp_reset_query();
    return $list;
}
add_shortcode('tthumb', 'testimonial_thumb_shortcode');
```

Comment: I have tested it and it works right. Could you explain what is exactly the problem?

Comment: How can I work it by using wordpress shortcode...

Comment: Still not clear - could you outline somehow the desired output?

Comment: I want to same output by using wordpress shortcode like  [shortcode]

Comment: I want to use the condition if($i % 2 == 0) {echo '</li><li>';} in shortcode:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, maybe this helps:

```
function testimonial_thumb_shortcode($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'category' => ''
    ), $atts));
    $q = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'testimonials',
        'testimonial_cat' => $category
    ));
    $list = ' <ul><li>';

    $i = 0; //init the counter

    while($q->have_posts()):
        $q->the_post();
        $idd = get_the_ID();
        $author_photo = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail');
        $list .= '/*Main loop*/';

        $i++; //increase counter
        if($i % 2 == 0){
            $list .= '</li><li>';
        }

    endwhile;
    $list.= '</li></ul>';
    wp_reset_query();
    return $list;
}
add_shortcode('tthumb', 'testimonial_thumb_shortcode');
```

Comment: I need to use in custom post query loop in a shortcode.

Comment: i really don't understand you, sorry

Comment: function testimonial_thumb_shortcode($atts){
 extract( shortcode_atts( array(
  'category' => '',
 ), $atts ) );
 
    $q = new WP_Query(
        array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'testimonials', 'testimonial_cat' => $category)
        );  
 $list = ' <ul>';
 while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
  $idd = get_the_ID();
  $author_photo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail' );
  $list .= '/*Main loop*/';        
 endwhile;
 $list.= '</ul>';
 wp_reset_query();
 return $list;
}
add_shortcode('tthumb', 'testimonial_thumb_shortcode');

Comment: How can I use if($i % 2 == 0) {echo '</li><li>';} in above shortcode?

Comment: Another thing need to know?  Where need to use other <li> and </li>. Actually the output will be look like: <ul><li><div>Here loop post</div><div>Here loop post</div></li><li><div>Here loop post</div><div>Here loop post</div></li><li><div>Here loop post</div><div>Here loop post</div></li><li><div>Here loop post</div><div>Here loop post</div></li></ul>